# References not getting printed

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am working on a tex file. Previously when I compiled it, i.e Bibtex and PDFLatex, it used to give correct results. But now for past couple of days I am unable to see references in my pdf. That is, when I compile my tex it doesnt show bibliography. Here is my example. The name of my bib file is amar.bib. I tried nearly all the solutions on this website, but nothing seems to work. Kindly help me out of this mess. Thanks in advance!
This is the screen shot of my error-
[image]

```
\documentclass[]{aiaa-tc}% insert '[draft]' option to show overfull boxes
\usepackage[crop=pdfcrop,
cleanup={.tex,.dvi,.ps,.pdf,.log}, process=all]{pstool}
%for using psfrags: all/auto
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{float} %% to float figures
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib} 

 %%My document

\bibliography{amar} 
\bibliographystyle{aiaa}
%\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here are two sample entries from `amar.bib`:

```
@inproceedings{kim2006chattering,
  title        = "Chattering free sliding mode control",
  author       = "Kim, Kyoung Joo and Park, Jin Bae and Choi, Yoon Ho",
  booktitle    = "SICE-ICASE, 2006. International Joint Conference",
  pages        = "732--735",
  year         = 2006,
  organization = "IEEE",
}
@article{li2009dynamics,
  title        = "Dynamics modeling and simulation of flexible airships",
  author       = "Li, Yuwen and Nahon, Meyer and Sharf, Inna",
  journal      = "AIAA journal",
  year         = 2009,
  volume       = 47,
  number       = 3,
  pages        = "592--605",
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us whether LaTeX or BibTeX are generating and warning and/or error messages. If so, what do the messages say?

Comment: Did you actually run bibtex? LaTeX by it self is not enough, and did you actually cite something? otherwise the bibliography will be empty (use `\nocite{*}` to cite the entire bib file)

Comment: When I do bibtex, it throws up "finished with exit code 2". Also kindly note that my .bib file is in the same folder as my tex file. Secondly the message thrown by pdflatex is:
1) !h float specifier changed to !ht
2)There were unidentified citations
3) There were multiple-defined labels. But it compiled successfully with 0 errors and 19 warnings.

Comment: Can you please further reduce your code, i.e., remove all packages and commands such as `siunitx` and `\DeclareMathOperator` that are not relevant for reproducing the error. Could you please also post the contents of your .bib file?

Comment: @inproceedings{kim2006chattering,
  title={Chattering free sliding mode control},
  author={Kim, Kyoung Joo and Park, Jin Bae and Choi, Yoon Ho},
  booktitle={SICE-ICASE, 2006. International Joint Conference},
  pages={732--735},
  year={2006},
  organization={IEEE}
}

@article{li2009dynamics,
  title={Dynamics modeling and simulation of flexible airships},
  author={Li, Yuwen and Nahon, Meyer and Sharf, Inna},
  journal={AIAA journal},
  volume={47},
  number={3},
  pages={592--605},
  year={2009}
}

Comment: Don't add code in comments, edit your question instead. And make your example complete. There should be a \begin{document} and a \cite command. And it should demonstrate the problem, so test it.

Comment: Please tell us more about the "finished with exit code 2" BibTeX error message.

Comment: While compiling my tex file I get the following warning- Citation 'slotine1986adaptive' on page 5 undefined on input line 509. 
Also I need to bring it to your notice that it is throwing the same error for all my citations.  I am not really pro in latex but this is really the most frustrating thing in my life!

Answer (score 1):

The `aaai-tc` document class requires citation call-outs to be formatted as superscript-level numbers. Hence:

- Don't load the `natbib` package at all, or
- if you must load `natbib`, load it with the option `super` in order to generate superscript-style citation call-outs.

The following MWE compiles fine; note the use of both `\cite` and `\citen`.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{amar-test.bib}
@article{li2009dynamics,
  title        = "Dynamics modeling and simulation of flexible
                  airships",
  author       = "Li, Yuwen and Nahon, Meyer and Sharf, Inna",
  journal      = "AIAA journal",
  year         = 2009,
  volume       = 47,
  number       = 3,
  pages        = "592--605",
}
@inproceedings{kim2006chattering,
  title        = "Chattering free sliding mode control",
  author       = "Kim, Kyoung Joo and Park, Jin Bae and Choi, Yoon
                  Ho",
  booktitle    = "SICE-ICASE, 2006. International Joint Conference",
  pages        = "732--735",
  year         = 2006,
  organization = "IEEE",
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{aiaa-tc}
% [drastically simplified the preamble]
% \usepackage[super]{natbib} % <-- best no to load this package

\begin{document}
\cite{kim2006chattering,li2009dynamics} % superscript-style appearance

\citen{kim2006chattering,li2009dynamics} % for "no-superscript" appearance
\bibliographystyle{aiaa}
\bibliography{amar-test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working at my end and I tried everything! I removed, kile, installed texmaker and then finally texstudio. But nothing is working! This is really one of those frustrating situations when you try everything and spend time on petty issues, when one can spend it on more fruitful things..:(

Comment: OK, let me explain my situation once more- I have my bibliograhy written in a file named amar.bbl(previously it was amar.bib), but both are not working for some reason. I have literally tried everything.

Comment: @AmardeepMishra Copy the content Mico posted and save it as `amardeepBibtex2911.tex`, open that file with texmaker. Press F6. Wait a minute. Press F11. Wait a minute. Press F6. Wait a minute. Press F6 again and wait another minute. The bibliography should be shown.

Comment: @AmardeepMishra - Broad claims such as "I have literally tried everything" are not particularly illuminating or diagnostic. (Incidentally, who suggested to you to place the bib entries in a file with extension .bbl instead of .bib? That can't possibly go well. For sure, I don't find it surprising to read that it didn't work.) Please follow Johannes B's suggestions step by step, and please let us know what you obtain. Once you get the correct output from the test file, we can discuss what to do next, in terms of your real tex file and real bib file.

Comment: Ok, let me try Johannes_B's solution for a second. It was my friend who suggested to use bbl instead of bib if bib is not getting compiled properly. Either way, I think I should give Johannes_B;s solution a try. Thanks for the reply btw